# Recursively re-link all multi-hop symlinks to directly link to final destination instead

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk

How would one go about recursively removing middleman links? For example:

```
somelink -> someintermediarylink -> actualfile.txt
```

would become

```
somelink -> actualfile.txt
```

for all files in a directory and its subdirectories (i.e. recursively)

Ideas?

Comment: you might work around the find command (*not only*) from `find .... -type l ` will  result in 
some sort of `/tmp/toto/titi/tata/tutu/kiki` for each where last word is link name & previous the full path  so you can first determinate & remove middle link & replace first one to point to the file.

Comment: consider (force) re-linking against `realpath` with `find -exec` one-liner

Comment: I've deleted my answer because I've got lots of issues. For instance, your links may be any mixture of relative and absolute and it gets maddeningly complicated to work with all the cases.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU tools:

```
find . -type l ! -xtype l -exec sh -c '
  for link do
    target=$(readlink -e -- "$link") &&
      ln -svTf -r -- "$target" "$link"
  done' sh {} +
```

Would change all non-broken symlinks to be relative and without symlink components in their target.

Remove the `-r` if you'd rather have absolute symlinks.

That assumes none of the canonical absolute names of the files those symlinks point to end in newline characters (the usual limitation of command substitution that strips all trailing newline characters).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Usage: ./relinkToFinalDestination directory_path
directory=$1
find -L $directory -xtype l | while read file; do
    next_hop=$(readlink "$file")
    if [[ -e $next_hop ]]; then
      final=$(readlink -e "$file")
      echo "Got final path for $file --> $final"
      # Update the link
      ln -sf "$final" "$file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: The targets of relative symlinks are relative to the directory that contains the link, not the current working directory of the process accessing the symlink. For instance, if `./dir` contains a `foo` -> `bar` symlink, that's a link to `./dir/bar`, not `./bar`, so `[[ -e $next_hop ]]` won't work there.